# Modelo Entidade Relacionamento Formulario dinamico

Tags: php, jquery, banco-de-dados

Criei um codigo onde o usuário é capaz de arrastar componentes e fazer seu próprio formulário.

Desejo salvar os dados vindos do usuário mas não tenho como definir quantos campos ele irá inserir no banco,logo não tenho como criar os campos na tabela uma vez que nao sei quais e a quantidade de elementos criados.Exemplificando: Se eu tenho 2 campos de texto no meu html como( email) e (nome) logo, na minha tabela do BD terei os campos que armazene esses dois dados.No meu problema não tenho como definir esses campos no BD pq não sei quantos elementos  o usuário pode criar no formulário. No link tem o meu formulário [Propriedade Disable usando Draggable jquery UI e javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252473/propriedade-disable-usando-draggable-jquery-ui-e-javascript)

Comment: Então acho mais viável você criar uma tabela chamada propriedades, e armazena os elementos com o `id` do usuário, `nome` do elemento e `valor` do elemento.

Comment: Existem sistemas que trabalham com as colunas `col1`, `col2`, `col3`...
Não gosto desse formato porque além de limitar a quantidade de elementos, não tem como saber qual informação o campo armazena.

Comment: Eu acho que entendi.Amanhã vou fazer o SQL .Qualquer coisa venho te perguntar de novo,pode ser?

Comment: Sem problemas, só editar a pergunta ou se fugir muito dessa criar outra.